# How can I update Skype for desktop to the latest version?

Tags: windows, skype, updates

I currently got Skype 7.7 installed on my Windows 10 machine, and I want to update to the most recent version, which is currently 7.18.0.103 according to SUMo. however, no matter what I do, I always get an error:

1. Automatic updates is enabled, but I don't get any updates;
2. Checking for a new version using the Skype Help menu option gives an error message and an offer to go through another website;
3. Going to that other website gives me a standalone installer which, besides offering to install crapware and hijack my browser, returns an error and an offer to go back to the original website with a slightly different URL;
4. Running the file I get from that URL gives me effectively the same file as I got from 3, which still does not work.

The error I always get is "Unable to connect to the download server". I managed to find the 7.17 installer through an url on the forums and installed that one, but I can't find a way to install the most recent version without hunting down the most recent executable.

How do I update Skype these days?

Comment: "Checking for a new version using the Skype Help menu option gives an error message and an offer to go through another website;" - What was the error?  It sounds like you are having DNS problems based on "Going to that other website gives me a standalone installer which returns an error and an offer to go back to the original website with a slightly different URL;"

Comment: @Ramhound The error was just a bland "cannot contact the server". It might be a DNS error though. Could it be related to the fact that I disabled all the "phone home" options of Windows 10?

Comment: There are no "phone home" options in Windows 10, but yes, if you have blocked communication with Microsoft then you have blocked your ability to updated Skype.  The fact Skype even works is likely just by sheer luck.

Comment: @Ramhound I find that a lot of things in this world around me just manage to work by sheer luck. I'm not sure how I blocked them. I found an article right after the release of Windows 10 that explained how to block it, but I can't find that article now.

Comment: If you can't tell us what you did or what you blocked we can't explain how to reverse the damage you did.

Comment: @ramhound I think it might have been DoNotSpy10, but I don't think I would have willingly used a program that includes that candy program. I also can't find any history of downloads in Chrome or Windows before November 2015, which is odd.